# Callback do ajax utilizando-se Spring MVC não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bem, estou tentando realizar uma simples chamada *AJAX* (o que já funciona), mas o *callback* não é "acionado":

```
$('#negotiation-status').on('click', '#button-add-destination', function (e){
       var departure =  $('#input-departure').val();
       var arrive = $('#input-arrive').val();
       var ckb = $('#ckb-label').val();
       var price = $('#input-price').val();
       var saleType = $('#ckb-saleType').val();

       $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: "departure="+departure+"&"+"arrive="+arrive,
        url:'/viatge/auth/addSelectedDestination?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}',
        sucess: function (result){
            alert("Aqui ele funcionou..." + result);
        }, 
        error: function(error){
            alert("Aqui ele deu erro..." + error);
        }
       });
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
   });
```

Estou utilizando o Spring MVC, abaixo encontra-se o metodo responsavel por tratar a requisição e enviar uma resposta:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addSelectedDestination", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addSelectedDestination(@RequestParam(value="arrive", required=true) String arrive,
        @RequestParam(value="departure", required=true) String departure){

    DestinationRequested destinationRequested = new DestinationRequested();

    destinationRequested.setArrivalDate(arrive);
    destinationRequested.setDepartureDate(departure);

    selectedDestination.add(destinationRequested);

    return arrive + departure;

}
```

O problema é que o `alert();` no **sucess** não é disparado!

Comment: Por acaso está entrando no método `addSelectedDestination` corretamente?

Comment: sim @denisazevedo, ele entra. O problema esta sendo o callback mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que é um um erro de digitação, está escrito sucess com apenas um **c**, quando o correto é **success**. Lembre de conferir esses detalhes na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Parece brincadeira @Juliano, mas era isso mesmo. Falta de atenção extrema minha. Obrigado.